# How to become a professional who plays chess?

Tags: learning

Currently, I am a good player of chess, I am a member of sites like chess.com and ChessCube.com and in Chess Online (Android application). Since I am a working professional, I could not spend much more time for chess which I fear would lose my competency.

I am not referring to the [Struggling to improve past beginner level](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4434/struggling-to-improve-past-beginner-level) link, but being a working professional, suggestions to improve my gaming side.

**Are there any suggestions to keep myself improving?**

Comment: What is your FIDE rating?

Comment: I haven't heard of a way to improve that doesn't involve dedicating time. Are you asking how best you can budget your limited time to facilitate improvement? How many hours per week are you currently spending on all chess-related activities?

Comment: The link provided by Bad_Bishop already contains good information for improvement which will work for players up to master level. It all depends on how much time you have to work on your chess to determine how much your game can improve.

And remember: There is NO QUICK FIX to improving your game noticeably if you're not a novice anymore. It takes both time and effort.